# Play2 / JPA / Ebean OneToMany Mapping, using a composite PrimaryKey

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I try to create a ManyToOne relationShip on composite key but when i insert my Pres2 bean  i've got this error :

```
[error] Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Duplicate column name "CODE1"; SQL statement:
[error] insert into Pres2 (code1, code2, code3, champ1, code1) values (?,?,?,?,?) [42121-172]
```

My projet is on Play 2.2.2.

Could you help me to solve my problem?

My First Id Class code for bean Pres1 :

```
@Embeddable
public class ClePres1 implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(name = "code1")
  private String code1;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
     ...
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     ...
  }
```

My bean Pres1 code :

```
@Entity
@Table(Name = "Pres1")
public class Pres1 extends Model {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EmbeddedId
   ClePres1 cle;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pres1")
   private List<Pres2> listPres2;

   ...
```

My 2nd Id Class for bean Pres2 code :

```
@Embeddable
public class ClePres2 implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Column(name = "code1")
   public String code1;

   @Column(name = "code2")
   public String code2;

   @Column(name = "code3")
   public String code3;

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
   ...
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   ...
   }
```

My Pres2 bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Pres2")
public class Pres2 extends Model {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EmbeddedId
   ClePres2 cle;

   @Column(name = "champ1")
   private String champ1;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({ 
      @JoinColumn(name = "code1",referencedColumnName="code1")
   })
   private Pres1 pres1;
```

Comment: Please post Pres3 entity, it looks like you have code1 column in both embeddable as well as in entity.

Comment: sorry, it's just a bad copy/past  i have edited my question. is always Pres1 and Pres2

Answer (score 0):

You have `code1` column configured in `ClePres2` embeddable class as well as in `Pres2` class for configuring @ManyToOne relationship. This issue will be fixed if you remove `code1` from `ClePres2`, but if you like to have `code1` in embeddable id for `Pres2`, then configure @ManyToOne relationship as below to avoid inserting code1 column twice.

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({ 
      @JoinColumn(name = "code1",referencedColumnName="code1",insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private Pres1 pres1;
```